# android -How to know if sms sent for my application

Tags: android

I've a registration form in my application , when a user complete this form , a verification sms will be sent to his phone number .

How can I know if this sms has been sent for my application ? For example, When you log in with whatsapp , it'll send a sms and when sms arrives ,it get the activation code from the message and automatically active the the app .

How can I do so ?

thanks

Comment: Why not checking the phone number the massage came from?

Comment: Why do you need to know the sms was sent for you application.? You can simply read the contents of the sms and check if the activation code is present, if present then you can proceed...It is less probable that some other application or user can send the code at the same time...